# React Apollo - handle filtering

Tags: reactjs, filter, react-apollo, react-props

I am currently building a react app with Apollo.
My goal is to have a initial request that returns all data.
This data is then used in my FilterSidebar to generate all filters, as well as in the canvas, that renders the actual data.

If then a filter from the FilterSidebar is used, the adjusted filter variables will be passed to its parent. Apollo detects the changes and fires the query again.

At this point I don't want the data to be passed to FilterSidebar again because I don't want the filters to be re-created and re-rendered.

My question is, if there is a possibility to avoid passing props to the FilterSidebar again?
Or would it be better to create another Apollo-request, that doesn't use any variables at all, passes it's initial data to the FilterSidebar and can eventually be used again if the filters are reseted (load query from cache)?

Hopefully my problem is clear.
Thanks in advance

```
const App = () => {

    const [query, setQuery] = useState("{\"name\": {\"$LIKE\": \"%\"}}")


    const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(REQUEST_INQUIRIES, {
        variables: { filters: query }
    })

    // return loading animation here
    if (loading) {
        return <Loader />
    }
    // return some kind of error message here
    if (error) return(
        <p>Error...</p>
    )

    const doFilter = (query) => {
        setQuery(query)
    }

    const { edges } = data

    return (
        <div>
            <FilterSidebar attributes={edges} doFilter={doFilter} />
            <Canvas data={edges} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You can create one more state inside `FilterSidebar`: `const [attr] = useState(props.attributes)` init it one time and use `attr` instead `props.attributes`

Comment: Since my App component re renders when a filter is applied, my FilterSidebar re renders again and the state receives the new props. That's why I think that doesn't work.

Comment: when rerendering the `useState` will not be re-initialized and therefore it will be the same

Comment: Alright, then something else might cause a re-initialisation. When I log the state, I receive the new queried data.